# Arrays populated by external DLL if stepped over, not when running

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, kernel32

I am using `kernel32.dll` to import a 3rd party DLL's functions via the method below.

```
private delegate bool MyDelegate(float[] floatArray, UInt16[] intArray);

private static MyDelegate MyDelegateCaller = null;

public static bool MyMethod(ref float[] floatArray, out UInt16[] intArray)
{
    if(MyDelegateCaller == null)
    {
        IntPtr address = GetProcAddress(_dllHandle, "ExternalMethod");

        MyDelegateCaller = 
            (MyDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
                address, 
                typeof(MyDelegate)
            );
    }

    return MyDelegateCaller(floatArray, intArray); //*
}
```

If I debug and step over `MyDelegateCaller` (at `//*`) then the arrays get populated as expected. However, if I just run the code, the arrays do not get populated.

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Some more info: 
I am using this method rather than PInvoke for calling the DLL as I need to be able to unload and reload DLLs at run-time.
I have tried adding delays, running in different threads as test to try to simulate the effect of stepping over.
There isn't any cross thread calling of these methods, unless the DLL is creating its own thread(s), however, I do not have access to the DLL's code to verify.

---

### Update

So I've tried the following (inspired [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h80ttd5f%28v=vs.90%29))

```
            ...
            );
    }

    IAsyncResult result = MyDelegateCaller.BeginInvoke(floatArray, intArray, null, null);

    while (!result.IsCompleted)
        result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, false); //**

    result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();

    return MyDelegateCaller.EndInvoke(result);    
}
```

However, when I get to `//**` the program throws a `System.ExecutionEngineException`.

---

### Hack

Got my code working.

I removed the working from the previous update and put `MyMethod` in a `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` event. Looped over `BackgroundWorker.IsBusy`.

Not elegant, but will do for the moment.

Any better solutions are more than welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried adding delays, running in different threads.

Adding arbitrary delays is not the right way to synchronize between threads.  You need to wait for the other task to complete.

Comment: The delay was just to see if I could quickly simulate the behaviour of stepping over. Clearly the task needs to be completed, however, I have no way of determining when `MyDelegateCaller` is completed. I assumed that it would only finish being called when the function returned but the fact that the arrays are not populated implies that this is not the case.

Comment: @dav_i: Unless the DLL starts a new thread to do the task, it will be finished when the function returns.  However, you mentioned that YOU have multiple threads.  Only the thread that called the delegate will wait, you need to use a `ManualResetEvent` or something like that to synchronize all your other threads to the one calling the DLL.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I said that I tried running it in another thread to see if it made a difference. It did not.
Everything to do with calling the above code is on the same thread. I have no idea if the external DLL is starting it's own thread as I don't have access to the code.

Comment: Updated Q to try remove some ambiguity.

Comment: BTW, single stepping in the debugger doesn't change what thread runs the code.  It just adds delays.